# SQL. Не работает запрос EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql

Пытаюсь вставить в свою таблицу данные с использованием EXISTS, однако сервер это условие игнорирует и просто вставляет всем студентам оценки.

Хочу вставить в таблицу Mark только тех студентов, у которых, как пишу в EXISTS, будет id_group = 1, и предмет = 1, и преподаватель = 1

У меня здесь присутствуют таблицы: Нагрузка, Студент, Группа, Преподаватель, Оценка. В таблицу Оценка выставляются оценки.

Подробнее, что я делаю. Я выставляю оценки всем студентам, у кого группа будет 1, предмет тоже 1 и преподватель 1 (проверяю, если ли такое существует. Если да, то оно должно записать туда только тех студентов у кого .)

```
INSERT INTO Mark (id_student,mark,date,id_nagr)
Select student.id_student,92,'2019-05-22',id_nagr from nagruzka 
JOIN discipline using(id_discipline)
join teacher using(id_teacher)
join group on group.id_group = nagruzka.group  
join student on student.group = group.id_group
where EXISTS (select * from nagruzka where id_discipline =1 and 
id_teacher = 1 and id_group =1);
```

Comment: В EXISTS проверяется одна копия таблицы. В запросе - обновляется другая копия, никак с первой не связанная. Так что при наличии хотя бы одной записи обновится вся таблица, при отсутствии - ничего не обновится.

Comment: @Akina Вроде работает, можете сказать правильно ли сделано ? Добавил ответ себе в вопрос.

Comment: Ну работает - уже хорошо... вот только нафига нужен WHERE EXISTS? что мешает просто добавить таблицу `nagruzka` в источник данных запроса с соотв. условиями и фильтрами?

Comment: Вынесите Ваш ответ из вопроса в ответ. Вы можете отвечать на свои же вопросы. И даже через пару дней можете обозначить ответ как принятый.

Answer (score 0):

**Обновление, рабочая версия.**

```
Insert into Mark (id_student,mark,date,id_nagr)
Select student.id_student,96,'2019-05-17',id_nagr from nagruzka 
JOIN discipline using(id_discipline)
join teacher using(id_teacher)
join group on group.id_group = nagruzka.group  
join student on student.group = group.id_group
where EXISTS (select * from nagruzka 
join group on nagruzka.group = group.id_group
join student on student.group = group.id_group
JOIN discipline using(id_discipline)
join teacher using(id_teacher)
where nagruzka.id_discipline =1 and nagruzka.id_teacher = 1 and nagruzka.class =1) 
and nagruzka.group =1 and nagruzka.id_teacher = 1 and nagruzka.id_discipline =1;
```